# Compare finger print using Java

Tags: java, fingerprint

I want to compare 2 fingerprint images in Java. Can someone suggest an idea to do this? I know this question is a bit vague. But please suggest some tutorial / idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if i know everything shuld i post the question ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some algorithms for recognition...

Check this google code implementation: [FingerPrint.java](https://code.google.com/p/fingerprint-rec/source/browse/trunk/project/src/application/core/FingerPrint.java?r=44)

There is also a .Net implementation here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Clearly it's not impossible, since you've linked to two different instances where it's been done.

Comment: @mikeTheliar you're right. Edited, I deserve the blame :)

Comment: @Alboz u have answered it and saying its impossible!!! :p. Thanks man